# Java ConcurrentModificationException With Custom Array list

Tags: android, exception, concurrentmodification

```
 @Override
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            ArrayList<DrugsInfo> filteredList = (ArrayList<DrugsInfo>) results.values;
            if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (DrugsInfo c : filteredList) {
                    add(c);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
```

I am getting a Concurrent Modification exception here.Plz suggest how to solve..

Comment: at what line please?

Comment: for (DrugsInfo c : filteredList)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears (as i can't see the whole code) that you need to use an iterator:

```
for (Iterator<DrugsInfo> it = filteredList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    DrugsInfo c = it.next();
    add(c)
}
```